# QGIS values from 1:n related table to parent attribute table

Tags: qgis, one-to-many, relation

I'm confused since I don't really get the difference between a form and a table in QGIS. I've successfully created multiple one to many relations between my parent shapefile and child excel sheets imported in project. The values are there in parent file's attributes table's form view. Is there really no way to get those values in parent file`s table view? I.e. to add them actually to parent file table? I need the values from child layer for labeling the parent shapefile, and I cannot select the child table fields for label source.
I read that this can be done only by Join, not by Relations. So is there or is there not one to many join option in QGIS? If there is, how do I configure it?

Comment: If you have a 1-n relations you get several child value for a single parent if so how would you to add them to the parent table ? take the first value, the sum, the average, a list, ... ?

Comment: Thanks for answer! TBH I cann't see any reason why this couldn't be done just like with Joins - like added columns at the end of the parent table. There is name of the relation, that can be used to name the column if needed, and it's unique, so no conflict there. Yet, I see this as nothing more than an interface issue, since the values are there in Form view. Why they can't be like "reprojected" also in Table view?